# Jcheckbox inside a column in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, windowbuilder

I want to create a table where every time a new row is added, a new check box in a certain column will also be added. I've don my research but i still cant find the right answer for my question, and sometimes i find it hard to understand some of the instructions 
SO here is my problem:

I have added a check box inside the column (the "e")of my table but it doesn't show. The check box only shows if i click it.

```
package app.ui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import app.dao.item.impl.ReadItemFromDB;
import app.model.Item;

public class Inventory {

private JFrame inventoryframe;
private JTable table;
private JTextField textField;
private JCheckBox checkbox;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public  void InventoryWindow() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Inventory window = new Inventory();
                window.inventoryframe.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Inventory() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    inventoryframe = new JFrame();
    inventoryframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    inventoryframe.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 102));
    inventoryframe.getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    inventoryframe.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1365, 747));
    inventoryframe.pack();
    inventoryframe.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblInventory = new JLabel("Inventory Management");
    lblInventory.setBounds(56, 32, 234, 27);
    lblInventory.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    inventoryframe.getContentPane().add(lblInventory);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(56, 130, 479, 249);
    inventoryframe.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
    table.setShowGrid(false);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                    "t", "e"
            }
            ));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


    checkbox = new JCheckBox("borrow");
    checkbox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    checkbox.setBounds(360, 63, 97, 23);

    TableColumn sportColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkbox));


    doIt();
}

public void doIt(){
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    dtm.getColumnClass(0);
    ReadItemFromDB myReader = new ReadItemFromDB();
    List<Item> newItemList = myReader.showItems();
    @Override
     public Class getColumnClass() {
            return getValueAt(0, 1).getClass();
        }
    for (Item myNewItems : newItemList) {
        Object[] rowData = new Object[1];


        rowData[0] =myNewItems.getItemID();



        dtm.addRow(rowData);
    }

    table.updateUI();


}



/*public Boolean getColumnClass(){
    dtm.getValueAt(0, 1).getClass();
    return null;

}*/
```

}

Comment: _"The check box only shows if i click it."_ - Use a renderder, not editor

Comment: Have a look at [**this**](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20i%20met%20your%20mother#q=how%20to%20make%20a%20checkbox%20in%20jtable%20cell)

Comment: Im sorry , please elaborate more?? Can u show an example?

Answer (score 2):

> "Im sorry , please elaborate more?? Can u show an example?"

No need for custom renderers or editors. Just `@Override` the `getColumnClass()` in the model of the table, use a `DefaultTableModel` and use just use `Boolean` types for that column.

There a running exmpple below, and here is the important part

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Here's the complete code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTableCheck {

    private static JTable createTable() {
        Object[][] data = {{true, true, true}, {false, false, false}};
        String[] cols = {"Bibitty", "Boppity", "Boo"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        return table;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                new JScrollPane(createTable()),
                "Table",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE

Here is your code. Look in the `initialize()` method, where I commented out some of your code, and added mine below. Also I got rid of the `doit()` method. Also you should `pack()` as the end of the method, and also `setVisible()`. I also added a `main` method so it is runnable

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Inventory {

    private JFrame inventoryframe;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JCheckBox checkbox;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void InventoryWindow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Inventory window = new Inventory();
                    window.inventoryframe.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Inventory() {
        initialize();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        inventoryframe = new JFrame();
        inventoryframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        inventoryframe.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 102));
        inventoryframe.getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        inventoryframe.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1365, 747));
        inventoryframe.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblInventory = new JLabel("Inventory Management");
        lblInventory.setBounds(56, 32, 234, 27);
        lblInventory.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        inventoryframe.getContentPane().add(lblInventory);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(56, 130, 479, 249);
        inventoryframe.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        /* table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
         new Object[][]{},
         new String[]{
         "t", "e"
         }
         ));*/
        Object[][] data = {{true, true, true}, {false, false, false}};
        String[] cols = {"Bibitty", "Boppity", "Boo"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table.setModel(model);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        checkbox = new JCheckBox("borrow");
        checkbox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        checkbox.setBounds(360, 63, 97, 23);

        TableColumn sportColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkbox));

       inventoryframe.pack();
       inventoryframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Inventory();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE 2

Really this should be a whole other question, but I'm felling generous today.

Use this test class. Run it. When you click the button, it will open the `Inventory` class. You probably didn't instantiate `Inventory` in your button's `actionPerformed`. Make sure this class file is in the same package as the `Inventory` class file. And just run the class below.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class InventoryTest extends JFrame {

    public InventoryTest() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton show = new JButton("Show Inventory");
        add(show);

        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Inventory();
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new InventoryTest();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks, ive been studying your code , thats why i was not able to reply quickly, please help me because i dont know where to place what. here is my code

Comment: thanks.. im trying to study it, sorry for taking a while.... :( im new :( and i really cant get it :(

Comment: Where is it? Edit your post.

Comment: I changed my answer around to make it easier for you. This way is more correct anyway.

Comment: ok wait ill edit my post. SOrry im new to here so i dont know where the buttons are,, wait ..

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. I have to step out for a bit. So if this answer works for you, please don't forget to accept it. (the check mark);

Comment: hello. Thanks for your effort. Sorry if i cant pick it up that quickly. I added the revisions you made , but i removed some of your revisions like adding the main method . Sir,  i should not put the main method in , because i have a main method in another class. And the error i encountered when i pasted your code was: when i click the button that will show this class, it does not open :(

Comment: Really, this should a whole other question to post on this site. The original problem was solved for you. The right thing to is `accept` this answer by clicking the check mark, then ask another question on this site. I will be nice today, help you still. Look at my **UPDATE 2** . If you're don't understand about event handling, and how to make buttons handle events, then I don't think I can really help you any further. You will need to go through some tutorials.

Comment: I dont know if this will make it clearer, but im using Window builder in eclipse ..

Comment: you know that you don't _have_ to repeat the errors in the question code, don't you?  Downvoting reflex temporarily frozen, though ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra _errors_ or _bad practices_? I didn't get an errors testing the code. As far as bad practices go, the code in the question was eclipses auto-generated, so I didn't want to mess with it much, just trying to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Pink000 This is what you need to do with WindowBuilder. Right click on the button, and select **Add Event Handler -> action -> actionPerformed**. Then go to the source code and you will see the `actionPerformed` method auto-generated. That's where you need to instantiate `new Inventory()`

Comment: a null layout/setXXSize _are errors_ - but seeing your point: walking the OP through the generated code is quite a task :-)

Comment: Yes i know that.. if you will see the whole Project, you will see that im doing SOME things correctly, im just really having a problem with this checkbox inside the table because to tell you the truth, im just self studying.. thats why up until now Im still browsing for some answers.